# Wireshark требует, чтобы я добавил своего юзера в группу wireshark на NixOS

Tags: linux, nixos

Не могу выполнить захват трафика при помощи пакеты Wireshark на системе NixOS. Ошибка - `You do not have permission to capture on device "wlp0s20f3"`. ВО всплывающем окне предлагается добавить себя в группу wireshark, но у меня не получается это сделать. Я добавил себя в группу wireshark декларативно в конфиге, но это не помогло: команда groups выводит, что у моего юзера нет группы wireshark. Тогда я попробовал добавить себя в эту группу командой usermod -aG wireshark my-user, но это тоже не помогло. Релогин выполнял, не помогло.

Как добавить себя в группу wireshark, чтобы захват трафика работал без sudo?

Comment: После добавления нужно перелогиниться

Comment: Я релогин выполнял, не помогло

Comment: Что выдаёт команда `id -a`? В списке есть группа `wireshark`? Если нет, руками измените файл `/etc/groups` - в строку для группы wireshark добавьте идентификатор вашего пользователя. То есть должно быть что-то вроде `wireshark:x:1234:my-user`. После чего рестартуйте шелл.